# NgRx effects giving error and I cant seem to find the problem?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am coping this ngrx setup and I'm getting an error for different types are not assignable to each other I cant find what the problem is I've tried too change the types and cant fix it

> Git I'm coping : https://github.com/yanxch/loading-sample/tree/master/src/app/commits/domain

```
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Action<void>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Action, Action<void>>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<Action>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action<void>>'.
      Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'Action<void>'.
        Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'Payload<void>'.ts(2345)
index.ts(9, 14): 'payload' is declared here.
```

Effect:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Actions, createEffect } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LocationPinsService } from "src/app/services/location-pins.services";
import { isAction } from ".";
import { LocationActions } from "../actions/location.actions";

@Injectable()
export class LocationEffects {

    getAllPins$: Observable<any> = createEffect(() => this._action$.pipe(
        isAction(LocationActions.GetAllLocationPins),
        switchMap(() =>
             this._locationPins.getAllPins().pipe(
                map((response) => LocationActions.GetAllLocationPinsSuccess(response)),
                catchError((response) => of(LocationActions.GetAllLocationPinsFail(response)))
            )
        )
    ));

constructor(private _locationPins: LocationPinsService, private _action$: Actions) {}
}
```

Actions:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { ApiResponse } from "src/app/models/api.response.model";
import { locationPins } from "src/app/models/locatinon-pins.model";
import { createActionCreator, createBoundActionCreator, createType } from "..";
import { AppState } from "../state/app.state";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LocationActions {
    static GET_ALL_PINS = createType('[Location Actions] Get All Location Pins');
    static GET_ALL_PINS_SUCCESS = createType('[Location Actions] Get All Location Pins Success');
    static GET_ALL_PINS_FAIL = createType('[Location Actions] Get All Location Pins Fail');

    static GetAllLocationPins = createActionCreator<void>(LocationActions.GET_ALL_PINS);
    static GetAllLocationPinsSuccess = createActionCreator<ApiResponse<locationPins[]>>(LocationActions.GET_ALL_PINS_SUCCESS);
    static GetAllLocationPinsFail = createActionCreator<ApiResponse<void>>(LocationActions.GET_ALL_PINS_FAIL);

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}
 
    getAllLocationPins = createBoundActionCreator(LocationActions.GetAllLocationPins, this.store.dispatch.bind(this.store));

}
```

Effects Index:

```
import { Action, TypedActionCreator } from '..';
import { MonoTypeOperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function isAction<T extends Action<F>, F>(...actionCreators: TypedActionCreator<F>[]): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Action<F>> {
    return filter((action: Action<F>): action is T => {
        return actionCreators.some(fn => fn.type === action.type);
    });
}
```

Store Index:

```
/*  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
/*              TYPES                           */
/*  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
type Type = {
    readonly type: string;
}

type Payload<T> = {
    readonly payload: T;
}

type Action<T>  = Type & Payload<T>;

type ActionCreator<T> = {
    (payload: T): Action<T>;
};

type TypedActionCreator<T> = Type & ActionCreator<T>;

type BoundActionCreator<T> = (payload: T) => void;

/*  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
/*              FACTORY FUNCTIONS               */
/*  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
function createType(type: string): Type {
    return { type };
}

function createPayload<T>(payload: T): Payload<T> {
    return { payload };
}

function createAction<T>(type: Type, payload: Payload<T>): Action<T> {
    return { 
        type: type.type,
        payload: payload.payload
    };
}

function createActionCreator<T>(type: Type): TypedActionCreator<T> {
    const actionCreator = (payload: T) => createAction(type, createPayload(payload)); 
    (actionCreator as any).type = type.type;
    return actionCreator as TypedActionCreator<T>;    
}

function createBoundActionCreator<T>(actionCreator: ActionCreator<T>, dispatchFn: (action: Action<T>) => void): BoundActionCreator<T> {
    return (payload: T) => {
        const action = actionCreator(payload);
        dispatchFn(action);   
    };
}

/*  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
/*              TYPE GUARDS                     */
/*  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
function isType<T>(action: Action<any>, ...expectedAction: Action<T>[]): action is Action<T> {
    return expectedAction.some(e => e.type === action.type)
}

function isAction<T>(action: Action<any>, ...expectedActionCreator: TypedActionCreator<T>[]): action is Action<T> {
    return expectedActionCreator.some(e => e.type === action.type);
}

export function notNull(d: any) {
    return d != null && d != undefined;
}

export {
    Type, Payload, Action,
    TypedActionCreator,
    createType,
    createPayload,
    createAction,
    createActionCreator,
    createBoundActionCreator,
    isType,
    isAction
};
```

Comment: isAction(LocationActions.GetAllLocationPins), // the line with the error

Comment: I'm guessing you need `isAction<void>(LocationActions.GetAllLocationPins),`?

Comment: no i get this new error on top of the old one:                                                           
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'EffectResult<Action>'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Action'.ts(2322)
models.d.ts(3, 5): 'type' is declared here.
effect_creator.d.ts(42, 161): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature